# Why there is a gap between http requests in google chrome network?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In my application when I load the page, many resources are loading from cache. But between 2 requests I am getting some delay like as shown in below image:
[image]

Can someone please tell me why I am getting this delay (~300ms) between these 2 requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gap is time spent queuing or being stalled. This can be demonstrated in the example below, which shows four requests, with the last two being of main focus to us:

[image: requests]

**3rd request:**
[image: 3rd request]

**4th request:**
[image: 4th request]

As you can see above, there is an extra Queuing time in the 4th request as well as more stalling. Here's an explanation for this, written by Paul Irish:

**Queuing:**

> If a request is queued it indicated that:
>
> - The request was postponed by the rendering engine because it's considered lower priority than critical resources (such as scripts/styles). This often happens with images.
> - The request was put on hold to wait for an unavailable TCP socket that's about to free up.
> - The request was put on hold because the browser only allows six TCP connections per origin on HTTP 1.
> - Time spent making disk cache entries (typically very quick.)

**Stalling/Blocking:**

> Time the request spent waiting before it could be sent. It can be
> waiting for any of the reasons described for Queueing. Additionally,
> this time is inclusive of any time spent in proxy negotiation.

**Source:** [Understanding Resource Timing](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing)

Comment: Queuing and Stalled time spends are also shown in network panel. If you look the time spends of Queuing and Stalled, you can see that does not match the gaps time. I thinkk, the answer is location of the external files such as css, javascript files. If you link them at the end of body, get ready to embrace gaps. When I change the location of .js file, gaps are gone.